# command prompt cannot find program while where can

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

A quite peculiar case occurred to me. I am trying to set a minGW-64 environment and in the process I found out that I cannot access the compiler from command line.

Example:

```
g++
```

outputs:

> 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

which would normally means the system cannot find the file. But

```
where g++
```

displays:

> D:\Software\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++.exe

There is no difference if I am inside a virtual environment or not. 
`echo %path%` also reveals the path.
[image]
The funny thing is that I check it on a *Git Bash* which happens to be available and both `g++` and `where g++` works as expected (of course it does not do anything since no argument is given but it's recognized).

For example:

```
g++
```

> g++.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

Any ideas about that behavior?

Comment: It is in the path already as I mentioned. Also I didn't expect to do anything (as I also mentioned)

Comment: I told you it is already in the path.

Comment: Run Process Monitor (Micrososft\Sysinternals), launch the command prompt and then run `g++`.  This will show you the environment of the launch command prompt process to check the path.  You will also see if you get an access denied and how Windows navigates the search path.  Upload the unfiltered PML file if needed.

Comment: I downloaded Process Monitor and run it but for some reason it does not display `cmd.exe`. Even if I choose to include process from windows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the mystery.

In my *path* environment variable I had a path which ended in *"*. It can be seen in the picture above it's the 5th character I think in the last line. Anyway this caused the remaining paths to malfunction I think. When I removed it (the " not the path) I regain the proper functionality I was expecting.

By the way I track down the problem using [Path editor tool](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=patheditor2) which does not do much but greatly improves the optical editing of the path variable.